# Can I declare an array as constant with a fixed size without tuples?

Tags: typescript

## Background

In Typescript, arrays don't have a size when initialised. Therefore, if you try to access an element of the array, it can be undefined:

```
const arrayImplicit = [item1, item2];
// ❌ possibly undefined
arrayImplicit[1].type; 

const arrayExplicit: MyItem[] = [item1, item2];
// ❌ possibly undefined
arrayExplicit[1].type;
```

These show up as errors if you turn on the option [`noUncheckedIndexedAccess`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess).

Now, there are a couple of ways to overcome that. You can cast the array with `as const` when initialising, you can use a tuple, or you can use a non-null assertion operator when accessing:

```
const arrayWithCast = [item1, item2] as const;
// ✅ all good
arrayWithCast[1].type;

const tupleExplicit: [MyItem, MyItem] = [item1, item2];
// ✅ all good
tupleExplicit[1].type;

//  works, but annoying to work with and not a good practice
arrayImplicit[1]!.type; 
arrayExplicit[1]!.type;
```

## Problem

However, tuples become cumbersome to work with when your array contains many elements. My use case is I am defining an array of mock data. This can contain dozens of elements, so I don't want to maintain a large tuple like this:

```
const mockUsers: [MockUser, MockUser, MockUser, MockUser, MockUser, MockUser, MockUser, MockUser, MockUser, MockUser, MockUser, MockUser] = ...
```

And casting an array as const only works for arrays with an implicitly inferred type. If you try to cast an array with an explicitly defined type (`const array: MyItem[]`), there is a type mismatch. If you use a readonly type (`const array: readonly MyItem[]`), the type mismatch is gone, but the elements are still possibly undefined:

```
// ❌ The type 'readonly [{ type: string; name: string; }, { type: string; name: string; }]' is 'readonly' 
// and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'MyItem[]'.
const arrayExplicitWithCast: MyItem[] = [item1, item2] as const;

const arrayExplicitWithCastReadonly: readonly MyItem[] = [item1, item2] as const;
// ❌ possibly undefined
arrayExplicitWithCastReadonly[0].type;
```

Finally, I don't want to use an implicit array like `const array = [item1, item2, ...] as const;`. If I do that, then typescript won't prevent me from inserting incorrect items into the array. Since these objects can contain many fields, and it is important that all the required fields be present, I need typescript to ensure that I only insert instances of `MyItem`:

```
const array = [
  item1,
  item2,
  // ❌ this should be an error:
  { some: "other", stuff: 12 },
] as const;
```

---

## Live example

Check the full example in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCSwIFsoF4oG8qkgLigGdgAnASwDsBzAbigoENkIDjzqoBfGgKAGMA9hWJQySZAEZ0WHOBZQARADMBAhQBp6TeQoYATJgq69Bw4KPEAmadlw6ARgxIatzAgvtrjPfkJFOSBgRkMAAbMj4xaQBtMRQJTTjkSwBdXgB6dKhAGXIoMAFCQjJ7UJAoAFcKPQglSgg9HgCg+BDwyOBoiRSAOjs6H1N-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).

---

## Question

How can I make it work without using tuples, and without having to use the non-null assertion operator (`!`), but still preserving the type-checks for each element in the array?
The array is immutable, I only use it to populate the mock queries or assert values in tests.

Comment: no, defining an array like that still shows an error when trying to access an element

Comment: @szaman: did you check answers other than the accepted one? Because those define stricter types that seem to do what you want.

Comment: This is an option: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCSwIFsoF4oG8qkgLigGdgAnASwDsBzAbigoENkIDjzqoBfGgKAGMA9hWJQySZAEZ0WHOBZQARADMBAhQBp6TeQoYATJgq69Bw4KPEAmadlw6ARgxIatzAgvtrjPHkoCuFHzAZEI4fmAANhAAPAAqAHwAFACUWDxQGVAkEMB+JBQZ0QCqUBAAHkgUeoRQANqxALoAPlCxtQ1JAHTdDARFqejxUAy8nD5R5gBuDBF+0Bi5kTFwiChJyYliKBKaW8iWybwTUI56AGozc9KLUdEr4uub4jsWKJaatnLuRpyHUAD0-1KJBIAhIQA